# Is it possible to update an existing azure load balancer with new lb rules or health probe using arm template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-load-balancer

I tried with the above code but not able to get it right. And also, I can see that it is asking for the old rules. I am trying to update the new rules while not disturbing the old rules.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "lbName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lbLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "healthProbes": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "name": "HealthProbe-TCP-80",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": "80",
                    "intervalInSeconds": "15",
                    "numberOfProbes": "2",
                    "requestPath": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "HealthProbe-TCP-443",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": "443",
                    "intervalInSeconds": "15",
                    "numberOfProbes": "2",
                    "requestPath": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "HealthProbe-HTTP-443",
                    "protocol": "HTTP",
                    "port": "443",
                    "intervalInSeconds": "15",
                    "numberOfProbes": "2",
                    "requestPath": "TestPath"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "virtualNetworkName": "[parameters('vnetId')]",
        "subnetName": "[Parameters('subnetId')]",
        "frontEndIPConfigName": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
        "feId": "[concat(parameters('lbName'),'/frontendIPConfigurations/loadBalancerFrontend')]",
        "backendPoolConfigName": "qwertyBEPool",
        "beId": "[concat(parameters('lbName'), '/backendAddressPools/qwertyBEPool')]",
        "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('lbName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
            "location": "[parameters('lbLocation')]",
            "properties": {
                "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "backendAddressPools": [
                    {
                        "name": "LoadBalancerBackend"
                    }
                ],
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "probes",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('healthProbes'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "name": "[parameters('healthProbes')[copyIndex('probes')].name]",
                            "properties": {
                                "protocol": "[parameters('healthProbes')[copyIndex('probes')].protocol]",
                                "port": "[parameters('healthProbes')[copyIndex('probes')].port]",
                                "intervalInSeconds": "[parameters('healthProbes')[copyIndex('probes')].intervalInSeconds]",
                                "numberOfProbes": "[parameters('healthProbes')[copyIndex('probes')].numberOfProbes]",
                                "requestPath": "[parameters('healthProbes')[copyIndex('probes')].requestPath]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [update a resource in an Azure Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/update-resource), you need to specify the updated resource in a second template that's either linked or included as a subtemplate using the `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` resource type.

> First, you must reference the resource once in the template to create
>   it and then reference the resource by the same name to update it
>   later. However, if two resources have the same name in a template,
>   Resource Manager throws an exception. To avoid this error, specify the
>   updated resource in a second template that's either linked or included
>   as a subtemplate using the Microsoft.Resources/deployments resource
>   type.
>
> Second, you must either specify the name of the existing property to
>   change or a new name for a property to add in the nested template. You
>   must also specify the original properties and their original values.
>   If you fail to provide the original properties and values, Resource
>   Manager assumes you want to create a new resource and deletes the
>   original resource.

For example, if you have created resources from this 201-2-vms-loadbalancer-lbrules [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-lbrules), you just need to download the existing template from Load balancer----Settings---Export template. Then add the new loadBalancingRules and probes, edit the template to meet your requirements, then redeploy the edited full template with this command

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName yourRG -mode Incremental -TemplateFile ".\template.json" -TemplateParameterFile ".\parameters.json"
```

For example,

```
 "loadBalancingRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "LBRule",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_myLB_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": 80,
                            "backendPort": 80,
                            "enableFloatingIP": false,
                            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "enableTcpReset": false,
                            "loadDistribution": "Default",
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_myLB_name')), '/backendAddressPools/BackendPool1')]"
                            },
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_myLB_name')), '/probes/tcpProbe')]"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                        {
                        "name": "LBRule-new",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_myLB_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": 8080,
                            "backendPort": 8080,
                            "enableFloatingIP": false,
                            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "enableTcpReset": false,
                            "loadDistribution": "Default",
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_myLB_name')), '/backendAddressPools/BackendPool1')]"
                            },
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_myLB_name')), '/probes/tcpProbe')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "probes": [
                    {
                        "name": "tcpProbe",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "port": 80,
                            "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                            "numberOfProbes": 2
                        }
                    },
                      {
                        "name": "tcpProbe-new",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "port": 8080,
                            "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                            "numberOfProbes": 2
                        }
                    }
                ],
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run PowerShell or CLI from your ARM templates